# Installation of hybrid Intel CPU and NVIDIA GPU on Archlinux

Tags: graphics-card, arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

I am in the process of installing Arch on my laptop . I have installed Arch previously using AMD graphics in my old laptop. However , I can not get myself on with my new laptop.
When I invoked `lspci` I got the following result , the Intel VGA is at the top and the NVIDIA discrete GPU at the lower bottom.
[image]

After consulting with the Arch linux community on Google Plus , I decided to use bumblebee with the following configuration https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bumblebee#Installing_Bumblebee_with_Intel.2FNVIDIA . unfortunately I could not progress further as can be seen when I invoked optirun with the following command `optirun -vv glxgears -info`

[image]

Any suggestions or ideas how to install both Intel VGA and NVIDIA GPU ? Thanks.

Comment: aamof, that hardware is problematic in linux. here is Linus Torvalds opinion regarding it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_36yNWw_07g

Comment: I was expecting a more polite answer .

Comment: complain to Linus! :) his words, not mine.